# Oracle report migrated 10gas

Tags: oracle, oraclereports

We migrate the  oracle report to new Linux server,    reports are not generated and following  error message will appear:

> Terminated with error: 
> REP-2147418514: Unable to retrieve a string from the Report Builder message file. REP-2147418514:

Answer (score 2):

You may try the following suggested operations :

- First of all, and as ever, Take a backup of a `Report`(`rdf` or `jsp` or any other format).
- Convert the Report to `rex` format using the command:
  `rwconverter batch=yes overwrite=yes stype=rdffile dtype=rexfile`
- Open the `rex` file in a Text editor, and search for word `FONTSIZE = 0`.
  If an entry is present for `FONTSIZE = 0`, convert it to a valid entry such as `FONTSIZE = 1000`.
  `FONTSIZE = 0` implies that Font information is not stored correctly and it should be rectified.
  Save the rex file after all modifications.
- Convert the `rex` file back to `rdf` (or any format in which report was originally present):
  `rwconverter batch=yes overwrite=yes stype=rexfile dtype=rdffile`